# How can I get a history of the images I've created using OpenAI's Image API?

Tags: openai-api

I have generated many images using OpenAI's Python Image API (see sample code below). I would like to retrieve these images; however, I don't see them in the [DALL-E UI](https://labs.openai.com/).

```
response = openai.Image.create(
    prompt=prompt,
    n=n,
    size=size,
    response_format='url'
)
```

I've searched in both the UI and searched in the API documentation and community threads. This article is the closest I've found to an answer: https://community.openai.com/t/saving-and-downloading/27273/8.